# Netbeans autocomplete class methods

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

i've started a project working with Google Drive API, google libraries installed via composer, i primarly work with NetBeans IDE and i've never used object oriented PHP. I only worked with C# so i'm new to PHP. THe problem is that i got some class but autocomplete doesnt show any properties or methods of classes.

```
$files = $drive->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles();
```

OR

```
foreach ($files as $file){
      $res['name'] = $file->getName();
      $fileres[] = $res;
  }
```

It should like whisper methods getId() , getTrashed(), but it doesn't. I know that in Visual Studio this would work, but in NetBeans it doesn't. Is there any way to get autocomplete to work?

Comment: Does the `getFiles()` method have a specified return type or a `@return` anotation?

Comment: @ShiraNai7 well it just returns string

Comment: Then why are you trying to iterate a string?

Comment: @ShiraNai7 it doesnt matter what im doing, the thing i want to solve is why isn't autocomplete offering methods of $file

Comment: Yes it does matter. If `getFiles()` returns a `string` (according to you), it doesn't make sense to expect any code-completion when iterating it (you can't iterate a string in PHP). So either your code is wrong or `getFiles()` does not actually return a string..

Comment: @ShiraNai7 well according to Drive API documentation it should return a string, [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getName())

Comment: But I asked about `getFiles()` :) See my answer..

Answer (score 0):

The [`getFiles()` method](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/v0.14/src/Google/Service/Drive/FileList.php#L35) is documented to return `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile`.

This might be a documentation error. It is likely to return `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile[]` (array of file objects) since that makes more sense... But I cannot test this right now.

If that is indeed the case, you can hint the `$file` variable type like this:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    /* @var $file Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile */
    $res['name'] = $file->getName();
    $fileres[] = $res;
}
```

Then you should get code-completion.

Comment: Thank you very much, I also figured out that in PHPStorm code-completeion helps where NetBeans doesn't. Anyways thank you.